# Android Virtual Device Look Embaded window to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I am new to mobile development, i have a really simple problem but i couldn't solve it

For use Android Virtual Device, I installed Android Studio and downlaod Pixel 2 phone in Device Manager. When i started device, it looks inside the Android Studio window, there is screenshot [Virtual device in Android Studio window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6daOt.png).

So when I close the Android Studio, the virtual device also turns off, but I saw in the examples that the phone works independently. How can i change the appearance of the Virtual Device like this; [The Look I Need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1JES.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto settings->Tools->Emulator

untick check box [image]

Comment: I am very glad, thanks for your help. It works, i tried a lot of thinks but i couldn't this. Thank you so much